# JQuery passing NULL value to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to check if an email exists in a DB using JQuery. Currently, I am sending the email through an `$ajax` request:

```
$(".newsletter form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var postData = JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());
        var status = $(".newsletter p");
        status.removeClass('shake');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Home/AddEmail",
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "success")
                    status.html("Thanks for your interest! We will let you know.").slideDown();

                else if (data == "subscribed")
                    status.toggleClass('shake').html("This email is already subscribed.").slideDown();

                else if (data == "invalid")
                    status.toggleClass('shake').html("This email is invalid.").slideDown();

                else if (data == "noValue")
                    status.toggleClass('shake').html("No email specified.").slideDown();

                else
                    status.toggleClass('shake').html("Oops, something went wrong!").slideDown();    

            },
            error: function () {
                status.toggleClass('shake').html("Oops, something went wrong!").slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
```

And my controller gets it by:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddEmail(EmailA email)
        {
            string returnMessage = "success";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.ToString()))
            {
                return Json("noValue");
            }

            try
            {

                SqlConnection sqlConn =
                    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ICECONNSTRING"].ConnectionString);

                sqlConn.Open();

                string sSQL = "SELECT COUNT(em_email) FROM v2_email WHERE em_email = @email";
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sSQL, sqlConn) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = email;

                int count = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    return Json("subscribed");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
                Console.Write(es.Message);
                return Json("error");
            }


            return Json(returnMessage);
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class EmailA
        {
            public string email { get; set; }
        }
```

But the value for `email` is ALWAYS null. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong? I'm new to MVC

Comment: why `JSON.stringify` twice? and what `inputs` your `form` contains? also there's no need to use `serialize` here.

Comment: The `JSON.stringify` was just to force the data (thought it may help). I'm using a template which I HAVE to stick to. When I place `alert(postData)` I get `"email=whatever"`

Answer (score 1):

you use JSON.stringify two times, when serializing your form.

this will lead to a misformed request as in example:

```
JSON.stringify({x: 5, y: 6}); //"{"x":5,"y":6}"
JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({x: 5, y: 6})); //""{\"x\":5,\"y\":6}""
```

**UPDATE:**

as we learned from the discussion, the problem was a mismatch between the data being sent and the header of the request: for a `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` the values of the form need to be serialized properly. after the call to `JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());` form data is being sent as a JSON object, with no name that contains a string with urlencoded form data. for a regular post with the data from the form, the contentType header needs to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8", which will be set by JQuery if the data is $(this).serialize() so the proper way would be, as BrunoLM sugessted

```
....
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/AddEmail", //without setting the contentType
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data) {
...
```

Comment: Then i would suggest you take an input as a string and deserialize it using [JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) within the action. what happens when you post the values directly?

Comment: @NewAmbition if you post the form directly to the action, at witch line do you resieve the error?

Comment: Line 126, on `$.ajax({`. Thats if I try @BrunoLM's answer

Comment: and if you use `data: postData, //without the seccond call to JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Sorry, I should of said - I've taken all the calls to `JSON.stringify` out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31120/discussion-between-newambition-and-igarioshka)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `JSON.stringify` twice, and actually all you need is

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

[Here is a working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEdyp/)

Comment: Without the JSON.stringify I get the error `Invalid JSON primitive`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var postData = { email: { email: $('#email').val() } };
```